# in laravel my controller 3 filed value not passing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

> from view i am passing 4 values 1)name 2)user_filter_id 3)user_staff_id 4)ticket_id  but it not only passing "ticket_id" other 3 values not  working it showing error
>
> In View I am Passing This Value

```
<ul class="chatonline style-none ">

    @foreach ($ticket_details as $key=>$ticket_detailss)
        <li>
            <h3 style="text-align:center ">TICKET ID<small  class="text-success "><br type="text" id="ticket_id" name="ticket_id" >{{$ticket_detailss->ticket_id }}</small></h3>
        </li>
         <li>
            <h3 style="text-align:center ">SUBJECT<small  class="text-success "><br>{{$ticket_detailss->subject }}</small></h3>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h3 style="text-align:center ">NAME<small  class="text-success "><br type="text" id="names" name="names" >{{$ticket_detailss->name }}</small></h3>
        </li>
           <li>
            <h3 style="text-align:center ">ID<small  class="text-success "><br type="text" id="user_filter_id" name="user_filter_id" >{{$ticket_detailss->user_filter_id }}</small></h3>
        </li>
           <li>
            <h3 style="text-align:center ">STAFF ID<small  class="text-success "><br type="text" id="user_staff_id" name="user_staff_id" >{{$ticket_detailss->user_staff_id }}</small></h3>
        </li>
    @endforeach 

    <li class="p-20"></li>
</ul>
```

> My controller

```
public function manager_send_messageChat(Request $request)

{

  $this->validate($request, [

     'message' => 'required|string|max:255',
     'ticket_id' => 'string|max:255',
     'name' => 'string|max:255',
     'user_filter_id' => 'string|max:255',
     'user_staff_id' => 'string|max:255',

     ]);

       $input['message'] = $request->message;
       $input['manager_staff_id'] = Auth::user()->staff_id;
       $input['manager_filter_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
       $input['manager_name'] = Auth::user()->name;
       $input['reply_by'] = 'staff';
       $input['ticket_id'] = $request->ticket_id;
       $input['user_filter_id'] = $request->user_filter_id;
       $input['user_staff_id'] = $request->user_staff_id;
       $input['name'] = $request->name;      
       User_Ticket_Chat::create($input);


       DB::table('user_tickets')->where('ticket_id', $request->ticket_id)->update(['manager_staff_id' => Auth::user()->staff_id,'status' => 'PENDING']);

    return redirect('/ticket')->with('success',' THIS TICKET ASSIGNED FOR YOU .');

}
```

> I am facing error this

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_filter_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `user_tickets_chats` (`message`, `manager_staff_id`, `manager_filter_id`, `manager_name`, `reply_by`, `ticket_id`, `user_filter_id`, `user_staff_id`, `name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (f, GSL_00006, 1, SUBDOMAIN, staff, 1560777803, , , , 2019-06-19 03:02:06, 2019-06-19 03:02:06))
```

> my model
>
> ```
> class User_Ticket extends Model
> {
> protected $table = 'user_tickets';
> protected $fillable = [ 'user_filter_id','user_staff_id','ticket_id','subject','message','category','status','manager_staff_id','admin_staff_id','admin_processing','note_for_admin','prioritie','services','name'];
> }
> ```

Comment: I don't think some of your markup is correct.  I am surprised that ticket_id is getting passed.  <br type="text" id="user_staff_id" name="user_staff_id" >{{$ticket_detailss->user_staff_id }} looks like you intended it to be an input filed rather than a br tag.  <input type="text" id="user_staff_id" name="user_staff_id" value ="{{$ticket_detailss->user_staff_id }}">. ???

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `User_Ticket_Chat` model and make `user_filter_id` fillable

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_filter_id'
];
```

Comment: i Already added all, but showing same problem protected $table = 'user_tickets';
 protected $fillable = [ 'user_filter_id','user_staff_id','ticket_id','subject','message','category','status','manager_staff_id','admin_staff_id','admin_processing','note_for_admin','prioritie','services','name'];

Comment: go to top of the cmethod and `dd($request->user_filter_id)` this for check result got or not i think its not your code error. data not get from request

Comment: thats error define first for test value in input tag for test and try dump or die dd() and check you got result

Comment: is there any other way to store foreach value in database

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have not specified any 'input' in your view. For example `<br type="text" id="user_staff_id" name="user_staff_id" >` should be `<input type="text" id="user_staff_id" name="user_staff_id" >` and likewise all inputs.

The following guidance may help you if you still facing this issue.

You need to allow all the fields you want to insert for a query in model with 'fillable'. for example `protected $fillable = [......, 'user_filter_id'];`. Or you need to set some default value for "user_filter_id" field in db. You may use migration for doing that.

Please go through [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent), to know more about fillable.

Comment: Kyadastill same problems

Comment: Have you tried by replacing <br type="text" id="user_filter_id" name="user_filter_id" >{{$ticket_detailss->user_filter_id }} with <input type="text" id="user_filter_id" name="user_filter_id"  value="{{$ticket_detailss->user_filter_id }}">?

Comment: Please confirm your model "User_Ticket_Chat" has adequate fillable properties because you are inserting record using "User_Ticket_Chat" model.