# is there any way to store foreach value in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I am trying to store view foreach value in database using controller Is there any other way to store value by controller without view foreach

**View**

```
@foreach ($ticket_details as $key=>$ticket_detailss)
        <li>
            <h3 style="text-align:center ">TICKET ID<small  class="text-success "><br type="text" id="ticket_id" name="ticket_id" >{{$ticket_detailss->ticket_id }}</small></h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3 style="text-align:center ">SUBJECT<small  class="text-success "><br>{{$ticket_detailss->subject }}</small></h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3 style="text-align:center ">NAME<small  class="text-success "><br type="text" id="names" name="names" >{{$ticket_detailss->name }}</small></h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3 style="text-align:center ">ID<small  class="text-success "><br type="text" id="user_filter_id" name="user_filter_id" >{{$ticket_detailss->user_filter_id }}</small></h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3 style="text-align:center ">STAFF ID<small  class="text-success "><br type="text" id="user_staff_id" name="user_staff_id" >{{$ticket_detailss->user_staff_id }}</small></h3>
        </li>
    @endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
public function manager_send_messageChat(Request $request)
{

    $this - >validate($request, [

    'message' = >'required|string|max:255', 'ticket_id' = >'string|max:255',

    ]);

    foreach($ticket_details as $ticket_detailss) {

        $ticket_detailss['name'] = $ticket_detailss - >name;
        $ticket_detailss['user_filter_id'] = $ticket_detailss - >user_filter_id;
        $ticket_detailss['user_staff_id'] = $ticket_detailss - >user_staff_id;

        $input['message'] = $request - >message;
        $input['manager_staff_id'] = Auth::user() - >staff_id;
        $input['manager_filter_id'] = Auth::user() - >id;
        $input['manager_name'] = Auth::user() - >name;
        $input['reply_by'] = 'staff';
        $input['ticket_id'] = $request - >ticket_id;

        User_Ticket_Chat::create($input);

        return redirect('/ticket') - >with('success', ' THIS TICKET ASSIGNED FOR YOU .');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your controller and get the record as an array. the scripts will check and insert record into your db before displaying in your view. hope it helps

```
    $data['ticket_details']='assign record'; //this goes to the view
    $ticket_details[]='assign record'; this goes to the controller

    foreach($ticket_details as $key=>$ticket_detailss)
    //checking if exacts record exists     
                   if(DB::table('table')->where('id',$ticket_detailss->ticket_id)->where('subject',$ticket_detailss->subject)->where('name',$ticket_detailss->name)->where('user_filter_id',$ticket_detailss->user_filter_id)->where('user_staff_id',$ticket_detailss->user_staff_id)->first())
                         {
                        //if record exists, do not insert
                        }else{
                           //if record do not exists, insert into db
                          $save =  DB::table('table')->insert([
                          'subject'             => $ticket_detailss->subjecte,
                          'name'          => $ticket_detailss->name,
                          'user_filter_id'        => $ticket_detailss->user_filter_id,
                          'user_staff_id'=> $ticket_detailss->user_staff_id,

                        ]);
                        }
                     }

return view('blade',$data);
```

Comment: check this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56659578/in-laravel-my-controller-3-filed-value-not-passing

Comment: okay. its throwing error because the column requires information however nothing is been inserted into it. the solution is to make the column null in your database. so that even there is no data it will not throw error

Comment: sorry am confuse here. you want to store the foreach declared in your blade to db

Comment: yes i am getting that foreach value from other database table and store that value to another  table column